# How do you join the Stellar Slack channel

Tags: new-developer, beginners

I try to join the Stellar Slack channel but it suggests that I need an email from the @stellar.org domain. I filled out the form, but it looks like that is just to join the mailing list. Has anyone not from Stellar been able to join the Slack channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to https://slack.stellar.org/ and fill out the form to request an invitation. An email will be sent to you when you are approved to join.

Answer (score 0):

I jumped the gun a bit on posting this question. After filling out the form I later received an email with an invite to join the channel on Slack. Maybe this helps someone else in the future who is confused by the form suggesting it is to join a mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Stellar's website is showing that it moved to Keybase instead of Slack.

https://keybase.io/team/stellar.public